# Having trouble with overfitting XGBoost on a large dataset with many features and samples

Tags: overfitting, boosting

[image: RMSE Train vs. Test]

I have tried tuning every hyperparameter to avoid overfitting but I cannot get XGBoost to generalize well. While this dataset is difficult to get excellent results, I have seen a genetic linear regression algorithm do well. So I figure that XGBoost should be able to do at least as well since it is much more complex than a linear regression, and this dataset should have interaction between features. The genetic linear regression was more successful in the sense that train and test rmse both went down, although the rmse scores wouldn't blow your socks off.

Are there any other tricks I can do to prevent this overfitting?

Comment: How are you controlling the number of estimators? I strongly recommend not "hyperparameter tuning to find the best n_estimators" but instead, set "n_estimators" to an unreasonably large number and then use early stopping against a validation set.

Answer (score 2):

To control overfitting:

1. train with more samples
2. reduce the number of features (compare the importances)
3. reduce the maximum depth
4. increase the minimum samples at the leaves

Comment: 1. I have 400 features with about 800,000 samples
2. Ok, haven't tried that
3. have set it to 4, still overfits.
4. i have set it to 10% of the number of samples, still overfits.

Comment: I think your main problem is that there are too many features. Try about 30-50 features.

Comment: ok I will try that. out of curiousity, how do you come up with 30-50 features? depends on number of samples?

Comment: I used 5000+ features to train 100k samples once. It turned out that just 25 features would way outperform the 5000+ features.